# What's the simplest way to track visitors to an order confirmation page on a 3rd party site?

Tags: javascript, html, tags, analytics, tracking

I'm non-technical but trying to "build without code" (don't hate me)

My friend has a website. I have a blog. My blog sends traffic to his website and he gives me 10% for every visitor that signs up.

He is happy to put some code in his order confirmation page if I share with him. But not happy to give me access to his Google Analytics.

I want to know:
- how many visitors THAT CAME THROUGH MY LINKS made it to his order confirmation page
- how much did they spend
- what was the exact link they clicked through on my site

I don't want to ask him though. Is there some easy way this info can be sent to me automatically?

He also wont be happy to just share ALL his customer info, just the ones that came from me.

Does this makes sense? I've searched everywhere on the web but can't find a clear answer or step-by-step guide.

Thanks everyone

James

Comment: don't think there is such thing mainly because it requires access to user activity in another website.  He can do it with google analytics because he has that code on his site.  You would need to have that kind of analytics in his website code.

Comment: hey Scott, so how would he do that? He is happy to help and put code in his site but wants me to provide the instructions.